# Calling boolean function in while loop

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a bool function with an if else statements inside it. The first 'if' returns 'false' and the else returns 'true'. I want to call this boolean function in an other function with a while loop inside it. I have tried several times and I made it work. However, when I call the function it return 'true' all the time. How can I fix that?

```
bool secretCheck(string P1_name, string P2_name, char secret){
    secret =  'R', 'G', 'B', 'P', 'Y', 'M';
    if (secret != 'R' && secret != 'G' && secret != 'B' && secret != 'P' && secret != 'Y' && secret != 'M' && secret > 4){
        return false;   
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}

void secretLoop(string P1_name, string P2_name, char secret){
    while(!secretCheck(P1_name, P2_name, secret)){
        cout << "Invalid secret!"<< endl;
        cout << P1_name << ", please enter your secret: ";
        cin >> secret;
    }

    if(secretCheck(P1_name, P2_name, secret)) {
        cout << "Ok\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have the line `secret = 'R', 'G', 'B', 'P', 'Y', 'M';`? What do you think it does?

Comment: I think it stores the characters that secret can take. doesn't it?

Comment: @YassineEzzaim No. I'm guessing if you had warnings enabled you'd see some related to that line.

Comment: @aschepler I did not have any warnings :/, is that line wrong? how can I store a list of characters in that char?

Comment: @YassineEzzaim you cannot have a list of character in a char. You can have a list of character, or you can have a char. A variable cannot have multiple types at the same time

Comment: @YassineEzzaim Must read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thank you, I will check it now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure what you're trying to do with this line:

```
secret =  'R', 'G', 'B', 'P', 'Y', 'M';
```

A char can hold **one** and **only one** value. In this case, you're using the comma operator which drops the first value and returns the second expression.

At that line, `secret` is *always* equal to `'R'`, since it's equivalent to say:

```
secret = 'R'; // now secret is equal to the character 'R'
```

Then, in your `if` statement, you got that:

```
secret != 'R' && /* ... */
```

This will always be false, since `secret` is always equal to `'R'`.

Then, there's a boguous comparison:

```
secret > 4
```

This is also true, since comparing a `char` and a `int` will compare the ASCII value of the character.

---

To store multiple characters in a variable it will either have to be of type `std::string` or `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<char> secret_characters = {'R', 'G', 'B', 'P', 'Y', 'M'};
```

And if you want to check if `secret` is in the `secret_character` list, you can do that:

```
void is_secret(std::vector<char> const& secret_characters, char secret) {
    auto found = std::find(
        secret_characters.begin(), secret_characters.end(),
        secret
    );
    return found != secret_characters.end();
}

bool secretCheck(string P1_name, string P2_name, char secret){
    std::vector<char> secret_characters = {'R', 'G', 'B', 'P', 'Y', 'M'};
    if (is_secret(secret_characters, secret)) {
        return false;   
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: The comma operator has lower precedence than assignment, so `secret` is actually set to `'R'`. Same problem, though.

Comment: How can I assign those characters to a variable type char or string ?

Comment: @YassineEzzaim I have a hard time understanding what you're trying to ask me. You want a list of character or a single character?

Comment: I want to check if Secret does include only and only those letters when the user Input the letters.

Comment: @YassineEzzaim You don't particularly need a list of characters here. You could just start `secretCheck` immediately with `if (secret != 'R' &&` ... `&& secret != 'M')` Though something like `string::find` would be a different way to do it.

Comment: @YassineEzzaim ok, got it. Be aware that the user can only input a single letter, since `secret` is a `char` (a single character)

Comment: @ascheple oh thank you so much for your feedback I will fix that.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot I really appreciate your help !

Answer (score 0):

In your function `secretCheck`, you assign the value `'R'` to `secret`, completely overwriting whatever it used to be. Then, you return `false` iff `secret != 'R'`. Thus, you will never return `false`, since `secret` will *always* be `'R'`. It's unclear what you were trying to do in the first line of that function, especially since the meaning of the function is unclear (you never even use either string argument). I would suggest making sure your function is actually performing the task you want it to.